# Php validation for select option tag

Tags: javascript, php

My Question is that: i have created php validation for select tag

**the below php script is validating only state(select tag)
its not validating city(select tag) after selecting state from select option**

## PHP Script For Validation for select tag

```
<?php
$state=$city="";
$stateErr=$cityErr="";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
   $valid = true;

/*State Validation starts here*/     
 if(empty($_POST["parent_selection"]))
{
    $stateErr="*State is Required";
        $valid=false;

}
else
{
$state=test_input($_POST["parent_selection"]);
}


/*City Validation is Required*/
if(empty($_POST["child_selection"]))
    {
        $cityErr="* City is required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $city=test_input($_POST["child_selection"]);
    }
    function test_input($data)
    {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

## Javascript for select option

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ArunachalPradesh = [
    {display: "---Please Select---", value: "---Please Select---" }, 
    {display: "Itanagar", value: "Itanagar" }, 
    {display: "Arunachal Pradesh - Other", value: "Arunachal Pradesh - Other" }, 
    ];

var Assam = [
    {display: "---Please Select---", value: "---Please Select---" }, 
    {display: "Guwahati", value: "Guwahati" }, 
    {display: "Silchar", value: "Silchar" }, 
    {display: "Assam - Other", value: "Assam - Other" },
    ];

    $("#parent_selection").change(function() {
        var parent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent 

        switch(parent){ //using switch compare selected option and populate child
         case 'ArunachalPradesh':
                list(ArunachalPradesh);
                break;              
              case 'Assam':
                list(Assam);
                break;
                 default: //default child option is blank
                $("#child_selection").html('');  
                break;
           }
});
function list(array_list)
{
    $("#child_selection").html(""); //reset child options
    $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
        $("#child_selection").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
    });
}

});
</script>
```

## Form of select tag

```
<form action="select1.php" method="post">

State :<select name="parent_selection" id="parent_selection">
<option label="-- Please Select --"></option>
<option value="ArunachalPradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
    <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
    </select><?php echo $stateErr?><br />
City : <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
</select><?php echo $cityErr?>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: you have `$valid=true;` in the block that should be setting it to false.

Comment: @user1844933 Javascript for city select option

Comment: @Patrick Evans i converted that to $valid=false; still the problem persist

Comment: why downvote to my question friend

Answer (score 0):

well for starters you're setting $valid = true; in your city error case

Comment: i converted that to $valid=false; still the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_POST["child_selection"]))
{
    $cityErr="* City is required";
    $valid=false;
}
```

a (false) is required here and not true, passing a true means that your city even if it is empty it will pass.

also try to change the value in your JS_script and put it empty.

Comment: i had changed that to false but still the problem persist

Comment: if you still have the problem try an 'elseif' statement, or test your inputs before you initialize your variable with test_input($_POST["name"]).

and don't forget you Javascript, change the values
{display: "---Please Select---", value: "" }
rather than
{display: "---Please Select---", value: "---Please Select---" }

Comment: if(empty($_POST["parent_selection"]))
{
    $stateErr="*State is Required";
        $valid=false;

}elseif(empty($_POST["child_selection"])){
  //your code here the same you wrote
}else{
 $state=test_input($_POST["parent_selection"]);
 $city=test_input($_POST["child_selection"]);
}
function functionName(){//continue}

Comment: welcome bro ;) good luck. make sure to put your question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Besides the error mentioned by @JMP, there's also another error:

According to your javascript code, your empty city value is "---Please Select---" rather than empty, so in the php code, `empty($_POST["child_selection"])` will always be false.

Modify your javascript code, change all `value: "---Please Select---"` to `value: ""`

Comment: In your php code, add the following code:
var_dump($_POST["child_selection"]);exit;
Then tell me the output.